# play sound in java

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I have five wav files. I want to play them serially from a single Java program using sourceDataLine. But my program is not maintaining the proper sequence. Can anyone provide me code segment?

Comment: No. Show us **your** code.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Though make it for 2 sound samples, not 5.

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html)?

try this example from [here](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8c_PlayingSound.html):

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
/**
 * Use SourceDataLine to read line-by-line from the external sound file.     
 */
public class SoundLineTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SourceDataLine soundLine = null;
      int BUFFER_SIZE = 64*1024;  // 64 KB

      // Set up an audio input stream piped from the sound file.
      try {
         File soundFile = new File("gameover.wav");
         AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
         AudioFormat audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
         DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
         soundLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
         soundLine.open(audioFormat);
         soundLine.start();
         int nBytesRead = 0;
         byte[] sampledData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
         while (nBytesRead != -1) {
            nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(sampledData, 0, sampledData.length);
            if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
               // Writes audio data to the mixer via this source data line.
               soundLine.write(sampledData, 0, nBytesRead);
            }
         }
      } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         soundLine.drain();
         soundLine.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: this is at best a comment, no? :-)

Comment: @Scorpio: I wasnt finished yet.

Comment: +1 for the answer. "Edit following soon" would have discouraged me to comment.